# My VDB from embergen is blocky and pixelated

Tags: rendering, texturing, shaders, compositing-nodes, fire

apparently I have exported my vdb from embergen, and I have imported them to blender, they seem to be too blocky and pixelated, I have spent hours on trying to find a fix but no sauce. Any help will be appreciated!

[image: img1]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the samples and/or decreasing the tile size in the *Volumetrics* Settings in the *Render Properties* tab. Start and end work to increase resolution as well, however these settings modify the volume visibility based on camera distance, so be careful that your camera will remain within the distance range:

[image: Volume]

Comment: Well, that did improve it but just by abit.. it still looks very blurry and the animation looks so wonky, not same at all comparing to Embergen. I have added a new pic